# Does .NET have a built-in way of handling IsBusy (with depth) in ViewModels - or do I need to always reimplement it in every project?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

My view-model uses an `IsBusy` property, to indicate if background processing is going on.  It drives a UI indicator.  But "busy" status is not exclusive;  Sometimes more than one background operation can be going on simultaneously.  So I back the `IsBusy` status with a count, instead of a boolean, like this

```
public interface IBusy
{
    void IncrementBusyCount();
    bool DecrementBusyCount();
    bool IsBusy { get; }
}
```

Now I can just implement `IBusy` on my view model (I'll spare you the implementation -- it's simple) and now my view-model properly changes `IsBusy` to `true` when the first background operation starts and to `false` when the last one ends

```
public class MyBusyVm : ViewModelBase, IBusy { /* ... */}
```

I even wrote the obligatory `IDisposable` wrapper class (`BusyLock`) that does the `IncrementBusyCount` and `DecrementBusyCount` for me so I  don't have to use `try`/`finally` whenever I increment the count.

```
void DoWorkOnBackgroundThread(MyBusyVm vm)
{
    using myLock = new BusyLock(vm);

    // ...Do the long running background work 
    // ...Count is automatically decremented here
}
```

But this seems like such a common design pattern that I feel there has got to be something like already existing in .NET.  Probably better and more fully featured.  Is there?

(Years ago I once wrote my own version of `Lazy` before I realized `Lazy` was already there.  The same for `ISupportInitialize`  I'd prefer not to do it again)

(Editing to add -- I realize I can use a `Semaphore` but I was hoping to avoid any sort of Kernel object)

Comment: Sounds like you want a [semaphore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Hah.  Your comment came in just as I was editing my question.  Thank you though.  Perhaps I'll go that route anyway.  My desire to avoid it might be overkill

Comment: Not to my knowledge, no - because *even if* this already existed in .NET you would need to awkwardly compose it either as a contained object (which breaks all your XAML data-binding) or forward all its members and add new DependencyProperties - which is effectively the same amount of work (if not more...). There are plenty of _essential_ and repetitive things, especially in UI-land, which _cannot_ really exist in a library, and I feel this is one of those things.

Comment: A `Semaphore` isn't of any use here: you aren't performing low-level cross-thread synchronziation or representing resource ownership, signalling or control/capacity in a threading scenario, and you certainly can't use `Semaphore` as a ViewModel object/property in WPF.

Comment: There is a [SemaphoreSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=net-7.0) which doesn't use a kernel object.

Comment: @Dai exactly.  Still regardless of whether I use `Semaphore`, `SemaphoreSlim`, or `Interlocked` to implement this, if even this interface or something like it exists I'd prefer to implement that rather than create my own.  But I can find nothing like it.

Comment: BTW, shouldn't your `IBusy` extend `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: No.  The `ViewModelBase` base class does that.

Comment: @Joe `interface` types can be implemented by any class - some other class _that doesn't_ inherit from `ViewModelBase` can implement `IBusy` but it won't work in WPF because it doesn't also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` - that's why you should add it.

Comment: @Dai - That doesn't matter.  Implementing a property in an interface is not a guarantee that WPF can bind to it.  WPF is an implementation detail of this implementation, not part of the interface

Comment: That's kinda moot given that ViewModel classes for WPF are _really_ not portable to other frameworks, even other XAML-based platforms like UWP and Xamarin Forms - even trying to do unit-tests with WPF ViewModel classes is a pain due to how property-change events pass through the `Dispatcher`. But I digress... so let's just say I respectfully disagree :)

Comment: That's true but I don't need the view-model to be portable.  I would, however, like the *interface* to be as portable as possible.   Will I actually port it?  Unlikely.  But I've learned never to bog down interfaces with anything more than you have to

Comment: Not that I know of. If this busy-ness is happening over multiple threads, you may want to use the `Interlocked` class to manage your busy counting